# How to send packets in multiple pcap files using DPDK pktgen?

Tags: pcap, dpdk

- pktgen version: 3.4.2
- there are multiple pcap files, and how to send those packets in multiple pcap files using DPDK pktgen?

How to use **PKTGEN** sent all pcap files in **in a directory**.

- First, When I use this cmd, it just send one packet **Forever** and no stop.

```sh
./pktgen  -l 0-1 -n 3 -- -P -m "[1].0" -s 0:/pcap/test.pcap
```

- I tried several ways but not work.

Comment: I highly recommend the question title to be edited. I think your real intention is `there are multiple pcap files, and you need to know how to send those packets in multiple pcap files using DPDK pktgen. Is this information correct?`. If yes, the current information shared is misleading as it asks `how can one send a lot of pcap files in one directory`. can you please confirm `As Soon Aa Possible`.

Comment: @VipinVarghese Thanks, I changed the title.

Comment: have you cross-check and compare your findings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current DPDK pktgen has the option `-s P:file`, which allows specific PCAP file to associated to a DPDK port. Based on the contents of the PCAP file, either a single packet or multiple packets will be continuously sent through the selected DPDK port via PKTGEN.

using options like `rate, count` one can control the behaviour. Both the option to select multiple PCAP over a port is not present in `Command-Line`. Through `LUA` scripts the option is also not present too.

the only valid option is `page pcap` to highlight the port and packets in use and `pcap show` to display pcap relevant information. Hence the option `to send packets from multiple pcap files via cmd line or Lua script is absent`.

Note: an alternative to exploring would be DPDK hosted project `https://doc.dpdk.org/burst-replay/` as the current logic reads the packets into mbuf memory and sends from the cache. You can either modify DPDK-PKTGEN or BUTST-REPLAY to accept pcap folder and read multiple pcap files to achieve the same.

Comment: @0x4c2 if the answer has addressed the issue, please accept and upvote to close the loop.